# Store value with new line in variable

Tags: shell

Can you any one help me with this issue in unix 
The variable value is populated from file
but i want the value should come in same was as it was in file but store it in a variable

```
Table_Name_v=First_word\nSUMMARY_Details_V\nDETAIL_FACT_V'
```

I want to store this in variable like

```
Table_Name_v_new=First_word
            SUMMARY_Details_V
            DETAIL_FACT_V
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does the file contain literal `\n` sequences? Then when you say it should be the same in the variable as it was in the file, where do the linebreaks come from? What about the leading blanks?

Comment: (1) Literal `\n` sequences, or literal newlines? (2) What do you mean in your comment on Rob's answer about wanting to "break the word"? What does that mean in practice? If you want to split on newlines into separate variables or separate array elements, I don't see anything *at all* about that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 table_Name="First_word
 SUMMARY_Details_V
 DETAIL_FACT_V"
```

or

```
 table_Name=$(printf "First_word\nSUMMARY_Details_V\nDETAIL_FACT_V")
```

Comment: Hi @Rob, Thanks for the comment. I am gating the value in variable Table_Name_v.Can you help me how can i break the word and new line and store it in another variable

Comment: Not sure what you mean? show us an example of the variable and script source and input data if possible.

Comment: I have one input in a variable Table_Name_v=First_word\nSUMMARY_Details_V\nDETAIL_FACT_V.   I want the "\n" should treat as new line and give output as                    Table_Name_v_new=First_word
            SUMMARY_Details_V
            DETAIL_FACT_V (Output as i have given above)

Comment: what shell are you in.. because considering the question you are asking I am not sure that you know, and depending on what you are using the answer could be different. what do you get when you execute "echo $0"?